# jQuery Datatable restore rows after filtering through function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable and using an external filter function to filter out some rows based on classes

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(oSettings, data, dataIndex) {
        if (oSettings.nTable != document.getElementById( 'bt-datatable' ))   {
            return true
        }
        var rowNode = $(table.row(dataIndex).node());
        if (rowNode.hasClass('def-class') || rowNode.hasClass('abc-class')) {
            return rowNode;
        }
    }
);
table.draw();
```

Now the filter works just fine it filters out based on the def-class and abc-class.
But I cant just get back all the rows this function has filtered. I wanted to restore back the rows on a click event.

Comment: your filter contains no way to turn itself off.  You will need a button, checkbox or something in your search function to see if it should be applied or not.

Comment: after i have filtered out the rows .. i need them back on a click of a button . i haven't shown that button here .. i just need a function how to get back the rows

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of what you are trying to do. Some of my labels etc are different because I used it on an existing code.  I put the button in the table def.

```
    $(function () {
       // global variable for determining if the class should be filtered

        var filterClass = true;
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(

            function (oSettings, data, dataIndex) {

                if (oSettings.nTable != document.getElementById('tblTab2') || filterClass == false) {
                        return true
                }
                // I did it slightly different here but it does the same thing.
                var rowNode = $($(oSettings.nTable).DataTable().row(dataIndex).node());
               if (rowNode.hasClass('def-class') || rowNode.hasClass('myclass')) {
                    return rowNode;
                }
            }
        );


            $('#tblTab2').DataTable({
                dom: 'tB', buttons: [{
                    text: "Filter", action:
                        function (e, dt, node, config) { filterClass = !filterClass; dt.draw(); }
                }]
            });

});
```